# plot directly done with gnuplot and input data using a pipe

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have input that I generate directly from Bash (representing `y=x^2`)

```
for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do printf "%3d %3d\n" $((i)) $((i*i)); done
```

I would like to plot these input data with gnuplot and using if possible with a pipe.

I tried to do naively :

```
for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do printf "%3d %3d\n" $((i)) $((i*i)); done < gnuplot -e "plot u 1:2 w l"
```

but this can't work because I printf `sequentially` the values `(i,i^2)`.

I tried to use `echo -e` (before the redirection "`<`" of gnuplot) :

`echo -e $(for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do printf "%3d %3d\n" $((i)) $((i*i)); done )`

on above command (`for loop`) to find a way to store the 2 entire colums of values and then pass them to gnuplot command, but with this solution, I don't produce 2 columns (I get only a row of data).

Someone could help me to plot the generated data with gnuplot using a pipe (i.e with only one command line)

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to send data as columns? it is not clear how you want to send it, can you show it with a proper example?

Comment: I would like to plot data generated by my **for loop** and pipe them directly into gnuplot (if it is possible). My issue is that I can't store this data flow like a standard dat file (i.e with the classic way of using gnuplot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pipe the data to gnuplot with `for ... | gnuplot -e ...` and you must tell gnuplot to read from stdin with `plot '-'`:

```
for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do printf "%3d %3d\n" $((i)) $((i*i)); done | gnuplot -e "set terminal pngcairo; set output 'blubb.png'; plot '-' u 1:2 w l"
```

Comment: @youpilat13: Note that Gnuplot also supports data manipulation, you can for example achieve a similar result like this: `seq 100 | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "-" u 1:($1**2) w l'`